# log4j warning connecting to apache Phoenix database

Tags: java, apache, hbase, jdb, apache-phoenix

I have Apache Phoenix installed on a cloudera cluster. I'm trying to connect to the database and run some simple SQL commands. My code is below. I'm creating an executable jar file locally and running it on the cluster.

I'm getting the following warnings. Would anybody know what they are.

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.


package mysqljbdctest;
import java.sql.*
public class PhoenixJDBC {

public static void main(String args[]) {

String connectionURL = "jdbc:phoenix:52.153.31.118:2181,52.153.111.8:2181,52.134.169.130:2181";

try {
    //Register JDBC Driver
    Class.forName("org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixDriver").newInstance();

    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:phoenix:54.154.34.128","","");

    //Create a Statement class to execute the SQL statement
    Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();

    //Execute the SQL statement and get the results in a Resultset
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from STOCK_SYMBOL");

    // Iterate through the ResultSet, displaying two values
    // for each row using the getString method

    while (rs.next())
        System.out.println("Name= " + rs.getString("host"));
}
catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add log4j.xml or log4j.properties in your classpath and retry,
    For standalone Java app, make sure the log4j.properties file is under the project/classes directory
    For Java web applications, make sure the log4j.properties file is under the WEB-INF/classes directory
below is a sample

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, stdout, file 
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}   %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```